# How to ensure view appears above other views when iterating with ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

[image: Notice the 'capsule' shape opening up to the right is under the green-purple bar.]I have a SwiftUI view that is a circular view which when tapped opens up and is supposed to extend over the UI to its right. How can I make sure that it will appear atop the other ui? The other UI elements were created using a ForEach loop.  I tried zindex but it doesn't do the trick. What am I missing?

```
ZStack {
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("ALL WORKSTATIONS")
    ZStack {

      ChartBackground()

      HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 15.0) {



        ForEach(Array(zip(1..., dataPoints)), id: \.1.id) { number, point in
          VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {



          DataCircle().zIndex(10)
          ChartBar(percentage: point.percentage).zIndex(-1)
          Text(point.month)
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .frame(width: 25.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .bottom)
        .animation(.default)
      }
    }
    .offset(x: 30, y: 20)
       }
      .frame(width: 500, height: 300, alignment: .center)
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am thinking the problem has something to do with the ForEach loop for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.zIndex have effect for views **within one container**. So to solve your case, as I assume expanded `DataCircle` on click, you need to increase zIndex of entire bar `VStack` per that click by introducing some kind of handling selection.

Here is simplified replicated demo to show the effect

[image: demo]

```
struct TestBarZIndex: View {
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("ALL WORKSTATIONS")
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)//ChartBackground()
                    HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 15.0) {
                        ForEach(1...10) { number in
                            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                                Spacer()
                                ZStack() { // DataCircle()
                                    Circle().fill(Color.pink).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                        .onTapGesture { self.selection = number }
                                    if number == self.selection {
                                        Text("Top Description").fixedSize()
                                    }
                                }
                                Rectangle().fill(Color.green) // ChartBar()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: CGFloat(Int.random(in: 40...150)))
                                Text("Jun")
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }.zIndex(number == self.selection ? 1 : 0) // << here !!
                            .frame(width: 25.0, height: 200.0, alignment: .bottom)
                            .animation(.default)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}
```