# SwiftUi - Drag item on top of everything. global zIndex

Tags: swiftui

I have various elements scattered all across the interface. I want to make some buttons draggable and when I drag one, I want it to stay on top of every other element of the interface, not matter where it its, its position, its hierarcy.

How to have a "global zIndex" in SwiftUI that allows to have one element floating over everything else in the interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847909/12299030? or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798786/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi the examples you link all refer to close and related objects that belong to the same ZStack. I need to drag an object from one part of the interface over a separated object on another part of the view

Comment: Global zIndex seems so useful. I don't know why swiftUI doesn't support it.

Comment: @pistacchio Did you ever manage to solve this? Seems odd Swiftui doesn't have a draggable element that automatically goes above everything else.